# Help on finding the range of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

$f :\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ which associates $(x,y)$ to $(x, x+y)$

I need to find the range which I did:

$\text{Range} = \{x(1,1) + y(0,1) | x, y \ \text{belongs to} \ \Bbb R\}$

But somehow this is equal to  $\Bbb R^2$ and thus this linear map is surjective. How the range can be equal to $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Ask yourself: can we map to any point $(a,b)$ using this map? For example, we can map to $(1,0)$ by using the input $(1,-1)$.

Comment: yes but my range is equal to {x(1,1) + y(0,1) | x, y belongs to ℝ} which is clearly not ℝ² = {x(1,0) + y(0,1) | x, y belongs to ℝ}

Comment: You are missing the point. We can write $$(a,b)=a(1,1)+(b-a)(0,1).$$ Thus any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can also be written as a combination of $(1,1)$ and $(0,1)$. So, if I want to have the output $(a,b)$, then we can choose the input as $(a,b-a)$.

Comment: I start to understand thank you .

Comment: @AlgoRithme If one of the answers below worked for you personally, please accept it by clicking on the check-mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\text{Range} (f)=\{(x,x+y)\vert x,y\in\Bbb R\}$ and $\Bbb R^2=\{(a,b)\vert a,b\in\Bbb R\}$ be sets. We will prove that $\text{Range} (f)=\Bbb R^2$. In other words, we will prove that $\text{Range} (f)\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^2\subseteq\text{Range} (f)$.

Let $u\in\text{Range} (f)$ be arbitrary. Then $u=(x,x+y)=(x,z)$, where $z:=x+y$. Since $x\in\Bbb R$ and $z\in\Bbb R$, it follows that $u\in\Bbb R^2$. Therefore, $\text{Range} (f)\subseteq\Bbb R^2$.

Let $v\in\Bbb R^2$ be arbitrary. Then, $v=(a,b)=(a,a+c)$, where $c:=b-a$. Since $a\in\Bbb R$ and $c\in\Bbb R$, it follows that $v\in\text{Range} (f)$. Therefore, $\Bbb R^2\subseteq\text{Range} (f)$.

Therefore,  $\text{Range} (f)=\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score -1):

The key idea is, finding a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the range. Then, because the range is a vector space, it has to be $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Keep in mind that in the two-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^2$ you only need two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: that's what my teacher does but I can't apprehend how with (1,1) and (0,1) we can obtain all the vectors of R²

Comment: Abstracly that follows as a corollary of the dimension of the R^2.

Comment: In this case, we could calculate it too. Let (a,b) in R^2. We can see that a*(1,1) has to be (a,a) and therefore we need to add (0,b-a) to it to get (a,b). In conclusion we get a*(1,1)+(b-a)*(0,1)=(a,b).

Comment: but how does it seems so obvious to you that we need (b-a) to obtain all the vectors ? Is it just practice ? I really didn't see it that way.

Comment: b-a is the solution to the system of equations: (a,b)=x(1,1)+y*(0,1) or equivalvently (by looking at the components) a = x and b = x+y.

Comment: can you develop more?

Comment: Because (1,1) and (0,1) are linearly independent the solution is unique.